# aws php api - set region for a specific service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have different services running in different regions, most of which are in the us. For my ses service I need to run it on the eu-west-1 region. How do I set the region for only this service while all other services use the us-east-1 region defined in the aws config file?

I am building on top of Laravel 5.

I create the ses service as follows:

```
$this->ses = \App::make('aws')->createClient('ses');
```

Comment: Answering for anyone who runs into this, just define the region as a argument in the creation 

    `$this->ses = \App::make('aws')->createClient('ses', ['region' => 'eu-west-1']);`

Comment: I just recomend you put the region value in a ENV variable, to easy change it to each environment